# Can't run AWS lambda with sqlalchemy module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda

I'm using in my lambda SQLAlchemy
I'm using python 3.8 (It supposed to work also in 3.7 to I don't care to change)
I downloaded the module separately and uploaded it as a zip with my code.
It looks like this:

[image]

But I'm still getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

Any idea why? How can I solve it? Unfortunately, I must use sqlalchemy so I can't change the module

Edit:
This is how I import:

`from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import count`

But I also tried with package.sqlalchemy and got the same results

Comment: Show your Lambda handler function, including the `import` statements.

Comment: You can use the SQLAlchemy layer here; https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers, and then just import from within your code.

Comment: @MarkB I re-edit the question and added an example of the imports.